# How the Backlog Iteration of a Team be set via DevOps API

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a Power Automate flow that does a collection of things upon a form response, one of which being creation of a new DevOps Team/Board. From what I've found this requires 4 steps: create the new Team, assign a Backlog Iteration, create a new Area, assign the new Area to the Team. These are all done using the "Send HTTP request to DevOps" in the flow.

My problem is with setting the Backlog Iteration, the **current method** I'm attempting is to send a `PATCH` to the location `_apis/work/teamsettings?api-version=6.0` with a body the matches exactly the other Teams when requesting `teamsettings`, which looks likes this:

```
{
    "backlogIteration": {
        "id": "1591fdfe-9822-4549-9163-9d359a1699aa",
        "name": "{Name of the main project}",
        "path": "",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project ID}/_apis/wit/classificationNodes/Iterations"
    }
  }
```

I've double check that this matches the `backlogIteration` of all the other Teams within the project. The response from this method always returns a `200` code but the response body always contains:

```
"backlogIteration": {
    "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  }
```

Visiting the Team on DevOps confirms that the Backlog Iteration has not been set.

The **other method** I have tried is using the `_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations?api-version=6.0` address by sending a `POST` with the body `{"id": "1591fdfe-9822-4549-9163-9d359a1699aa"}`, matching the ID from the previous method. The response from this is:

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "TF400494: A team iteration cannot be created for the top-level iteration node.",
    "typeName": "System.InvalidOperationException, mscorlib",
    "typeKey": "InvalidOperationException",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "eventId": 0
}
```

I didn't have high hopes for this one to work, as from my understanding creating a new Iteration and setting the Backlog Iteration are different.

If anyone has advice on what the correct method to perform this is, or what might be wrong with my requests, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/teamsettings/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#request-body

You have to send the id in the request body:

`{"backlogIteration":"17d4dcfd-4bda-4d80-8293-a7ff4f7c9e06"}`

Powershell sample:

```
$user = ""
$token = "YOUR_PAT"

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$org = "ORGNAME"
$teamProject = "TEAM PROJECT"
$teamName = "TEAM"

$restApiPatchIterations = "https://dev.azure.com/$org/$teamProject/$teamName/_apis/work/teamsettings?api-version=6.1-preview.1"

function InvokePatchRequest ($PatchUrl, $body)
{   
    return Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $PatchUrl -Method Patch -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Body $body
}

$body = "{`"backlogIteration`":`"YOUR_ID"}"

InvokePatchRequest $restApiPatchIterations $body
```

Comment: Thank you, I should have inferred from `"defaultIteration": "8C2457E8-8936-4CDC-B3AA-17B20F56C76C"` that it would be the way to go, seeing as it returns with the same structure in the response body.